# Using Common Table Expression (CTE) with IN operator

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am trying to define a CTE and then immediately use it in a `WHERE` clause using the `IN` operator.

This does NOT work.

```
WITH T AS (SELECT 1)
SELECT 2 WHERE 1 IN T;
```

This does work, but I need to add a `SELECT`.

```
WITH T AS (SELECT 1)
SELECT 2 WHERE 1 IN (SELECT * FROM T);
```

Is there a way to get rid of the last `SELECT`?

I am using this query in the context of Foreign Data wrappers. The addition of the last select prevents the "in-lining" of the intermediate results.

Comment: No, there is no way to get rid of the `select`. The allowed elements inside an `IN` are either constant values e.g. `(1,2,3)` or a query. A reference to a table or CTE is neither of those two. Maybe you should take a step back and tell us what the real underlying problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: shoe the real qry - I don't see any case when such select would prevent anything

Comment: We are using Multicorn to define a bunch of foreign data wrappers against medical medical data (NCBI). We use one table to do a keyword search that returns a bunch of ids and then join the table with relevant articles. I want the ids to be in-lined and used with the IN operator and not have Postgres do a nested loop.

Comment: The other workaround is to write a plpgsql function that computes an intermediate query with ids and then does the query with the IN operator. But I find this approach clunky. I was hoping that CTEs could be used for such cases. Any way to transform a CTE into a constant or a query without using the SELECT?

Comment: `WITH T AS (SELECT 1 AS wtf)
SELECT 2 WHERE 1 IN (SELECT wtf FROM T);`